# Append Text with conditional statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. I'm creating a cell phone animation to illustrate probability. I have a graphic of an iPhone and buttons for all the keys. When a button is pressed the corresponding number shows on the phone screen (box I drew and ID as "phone"). However, there are some stipulations: for example, the 3-digit area code and 3-digit prefix cannot start with 1 (etc.). So I have conditions that must be met before the text can be appended. Here is my code for entering the number 1 when its button is pressed:

```
var phone = document.getElementById("phone");

if(phone.value.length == 0) {
phone.innerHTML = phone.innerHTML + "";
}

else if(phone.value.length == 6) {
phone.innerHTML = phone.innerHTML + "";
} 

else if(phone.value.length == 3) {
phone.innerHTML = phone.innerHTML + "1)";
} 

else if(phone.value.length == 8) {
phone.innerHTML = phone.innerHTML + "1-";
} 

else if(phone.value.length == 2) {
phone.innerHTML = phone.innerHTML + "";
} 
else {
phone.innerHTML = phone.innerHTML + "1";
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work. If I comment out all the code except something like

```
var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
phone.innerHTML = phone.innerHTML + "1)";
```

then it works. So I am assuming I don't have the correct syntax for the conditionals. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of  reflows.

Comment: If `phone` is an `<input>` element and has a `value` then using its `innerHTML` doesn't make much sense

Comment: what kind of element is `phone`? it it's an input just change all .innerHTML with .value.

Comment: Not explicitly related, but I'd suggest using a switch statement. Would make it easier to read.

Comment: using both `value` and `innerHTML` on a single node doesn't add up. Nor does a huge series of `if-else(if)` conditions. Look into `switch` (which "falls through" in JS), don't add `''`, just `break` in those cases, and set up a fiddle

Comment: `phone.value` returns the value that is in `<input id="phone" value="ThisValueIsReturned" />`. This element cannot have html inside it's tags (`innerHTML`), because it is always a self-closing tag. If you want the html between, for example, a `div` tag, use `phone.innerHTML` to retrieve it. `phone.value` will be undefined for a `div` tag, because it doesn't have a value attribute. If you have two elements with the same id, change the id of one of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Due to your working example with `innerHTML`, `phone` is probably not an `input` element. So you have to use `innerHTML` instead of `value` in order to get the string and compare its length.

Replace

```
if (phone.value.length == 0)
....
```

with

```
if (phone.innerHTML.length == 0)
....
```

in your conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
var addition = "";    

switch(phone.value.length){
   case: 0
   case: 6
       addition = "";
       break;
   case: 3
       addition = "1";
       break;
     .......//put rest of your cases here and dont forget default: break;
}


phone.innerHtml += addition;
```

The changes I have made:

- In a case where you have this much else if statements, it is better to use the switch statement
- I added a new variable `addition` which holds the string that has to be appended to the innerhtml of the phone, therefore you only have to change the innerHtml only once.